# Why won't kaggle accept splicing code the VSC does?

Tags: python, dataframe, slice, kaggle

[image]I wrote a for loop in VSC to splice some data and it worked perfectly. Now that I'm trying to import it to Kaggle, it will not work and keeps giving returning this error: "IndexError: string index out of range". The data I'm using has many random letters before the useful info. I'm trying to cut that information out in order to analyze it.

This is the code that worked for VSC. Is there a different method of splicing strings that I should try? Also the picture has the code I used, for some reason it wouldn't let me insert it here.

These are the strings that I am indexing:['SIT' 'FEED:DS:FRUIT' 'FEED:SY:FLOWERS' 'FEED:PR:YOUNG LEAVES'
'FEED:PR:LEAF BUDS' 'MOVE BETWEEN' 'GROOM' 'FEED:CA:BARK OR PITH'
'FEED:?:EPIPHYTES' 'FEED:LI:LEAF SURFACE' 'FEED:?:?' 'FEED:FB:FRUIT'
'FEED:PR:EPIPHYTES' 'FEED:FE:FRUIT' 'FEED:CA:?' 'FEED:ER:UNSP. LEAVES'
'FEED:?:DEAD LEAVES' 'MOVE WITHIN' 'OTHER SOCIAL' 'FEED:OL:FRUIT'
'FEED:UV:FRUIT' 'FEED:14:FRUIT' 'FEED:FN:FRUIT' 'FEED:MO:LEAF BUDS'
'FEED:ER:FLOWERS' 'FEED:ER:?' 'FEED:ER:MATURE LEAVE' 'LIE' 'FEED:?:FRUIT'
'FEED:?:DEAD WOOD' 'FEED:PA:EPIPHYTES' 'FEED:ER:YOUNG LEAVES'
'FEED:FD:FRUIT' 'FEED:CD:EPIPHYTES' 'FEED:LI:DEAD LEAVES'
'FEED:FD:EPIPHYTES' 'FEED:PA:DEAD BARK' 'FEED:CD:FRUIT'
'FEED:FT:DEAD WOOD' 'FEED:FB:LEAF BUDS' 'FEED:DS:?' 'FEED:18:FLOWERS'
'FEED:PR:FRUIT' 'FEED:19:FRUIT' 'FEED:NB:BARE SURFACE'
'FEED:ML:YOUNG LEAVES' 'FEED:PL:DEAD LEAVES' 'FEED:OL:EPIPHYTES' 'STAND'
'FEED:MK:EPIPHYTES' 'FEED:DS:LEAF SURFACE' 'FEED:FC:YOUNG LEAVES'
'FEED:FB:EPIPHYTES' 'FEED:CO:EPIPHYTES' 'FEED:12:LEAF BUDS'
'FEED:?:DEAD BARK' 'FEED:PA:DEAD WOOD' 'FEED:FC:FRUIT'
'FEED:SP:DEAD BARK' 'FEED:NT:UNSP. LEAVES' 'FEED:ML:FRUIT'
'FEED:28:FRUIT' 'FEED:36:FRUIT' 'FEED:MK:FRUIT' 'FEED:LI:STICKS'.......] There are many others.

I got it to look like in VSC: ['SIT' 'FEED: FRUIT' 'FEED: FLOWERS' 'FEED: YOUNG LEAVES'
'FEED: LEAF BUDS' 'MOVE BETWEEN' 'GROOM' 'FEED: BARK OR PITH'
'FEED: EPIPHYTES' 'FEED: LEAF SURFACE' 'FEED UNKNOWN'
'FEED: UNSP. LEAVES' 'FEED: DEAD LEAVES' 'MOVE WITHIN' 'OTHER SOCIAL'
'FEED: MATURE LEAVE' 'LIE' 'FEED: DEAD WOOD' 'FEED: DEAD BARK'
'FEED: BARE SURFACE' 'STAND' 'FEED: STICKS' 'DRINK' 'SELF-GROOM' 'PLAY'
'FEED: ' 'CLING']

Comment: Can you provide an example via the code formatting tool of what you are doing that works one place but not the other?

Comment: You need to provide a string example. Probably you can refine your regex.

Comment: Can you use a landmark, like start 10 characters from the last character rather than a specific index? Really though it is almost impossible to say without seeing the code you are using

Comment: Yeah sorry, The picture did upload at first.

Comment: comment an example string so we can help you. Is there any pattern in the string? for example You want to parse the string that is after an '?' ?

Comment: Here I added a snippet of the data. It was just very large so I didn't want to add, but you probably need it. Let me know what you think.

Comment: the data['Behavior'][i] is that string that you paste?. Maybe you can first check if the string is not empty or has a length more than 12. As it seems that your are hardcoding the places where your useful data is.